# Неправильный размер букв при отрисовке текста методом TextRenderer::DrawText

Tags: winforms

Программа на C++/CLI накладывает текст на изображение используя метод System::Windows::Forms::TextRenderer::DrawText.
Упрощённо это выглядит так:

```
auto g = Graphics::FromImage(img);
System::String^ text = "какой-то текст";
auto font = gcnew System::Drawing::Font("Arial", 14, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular);
auto bounds = System::Drawing::Rectangle(5, 5, 100, 15);
auto flags = TextFormatFlags::VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags::HorizontalCenter;
TextRenderer::DrawText(g, text, font, bounds, Color::Black, Color::White, flags);
```

На одном из компьютеров шрифт наложенного текста получается более крупным (примерно на четверть). При этом позиционирование текста правильное. Доступа к этому ПК у меня нет. Знаю про него лишь, что ОС Windows 10. На других ПК с Windows 10 такой проблемы не наблюдается.
В чём может быть причина?

P.S. На своём ПК проверил, что настройки размера шрифта в параметрах дисплея на это не влияют.

Comment: Пробуйте через WINAPI. Если WINAPI то же самое даёт - то это баг винды, и врядли получится исправить.

Comment: с++/cli - очень узкая сфера. Желательно указывать метку c++/cli. Ваш пример невозможно гарантировано повторить, поэтому... не вижу как тут вообще можно помочь. Если на белый квадрат наложить картинку, то что, прямо в пикселях высота меньше выходит? Составьте такой пример, что бы другие без труда могли повторить эту ситуацию не вспонимая как создать минимально-работающее приложение под с++/cli.

Comment: Я полагаю, что на C# будет то же самое.

Comment: Я накладываю не квадраты, а буквы. Я у себя эту проблему тоже воспроизвести не могу. Её получил пользователь. Я видел только конечный результат - файл с изображением, на котором буквы по отношению к изображению крупнее, чем должны быть. В результате текст не помещается в отведённое пространство.

Comment: Для текста я как то искал "матрицу" и нашёл - GetGlyphOutline. Если уже эта функция даст разный размер шрифта, то это означает что по какой-то причине шрифты разные. Возможно есть смысл брать шрифт на борт в комплекте с программой.

Comment: На самом деле там не Arial и мне приходится его "брать на борт". Начертание шрифта такое как и должно быть.

Comment: А вам именно TextRenderer нужен? Я бы посоветовал взять что-то более приближённое к gdi32.dll (Drawing) чем к user32.dll (Forms), потому что user32 может накладывать стили или параметры для прорисовки форм, которые возможно вам и мешают. Попробуйте или напрямую функции с gdi32 вроде TextOut или напрмер в Drawing есть [DrawString](http://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring) или любую другую функцию из System.Drawing.

Comment: Не обязательно. Но graphics.DrawString использует GDI+ и это вроде как не рекомендуется. А TextRenderer.DrawText использует GDI и это вроде как лучше.

Comment: Получил от пользователя информацию, что в настройках экрана у него установлен масштаб текста 125%. Попросил его проверить со 100%. Думаю, что всё-таки здесь собака зарыта. Только непонятно почему на разных компьютерах это приводит к разным результатам. У себя менял этот параметр и разницы никакой. У нас, конечно, разные сборки ОС, но сомневаюсь, что это влияет.

Comment: Глянул справку по DrawText, по идее можно взять MeasureText и сделать поправку на размер текста. В справке очень много рекомендаций использовать DrawString вместо DrawText. Возможно эти 125% и влияют на DrawText. Возможно процент применяется после перезагрузки?